# Can't throw a 404 error with urls that start with a question mark

Tags: wordpress, url, seo, http-status-code-404

So recently I updated my site from Joomla to Wordpress. (best decision of my life...seriously)

All of my old Joomla links were formatted with a ? right after my domain name like this: `www.example.com/?blah`

Now when I switched to Wordpress, I'm using pretty URLs that are formatted like this : `www.example.com/blah`

Now googles got all the old Joomla urls still indexed so when searched for it still gives you the old URLs. In my head those Joomla URLs should throw a 404 error. But they don't! They just display the homepage.

For Example - if you go to `www.example.com/blah` it will throw a 404 error because that page doesn't exist, however if you go to `www.example.com/?blah` it will show that URL in the address bar, but display the homepage despite the fact that that page does not exist either.

So my questions are:
1) will google eventually dump those URLs in favor of my Wordpress ones? How will that hurt my SEO and page rank - does google still see that as a valid page and keep it in its index?

2) How do I force 404 errors for those URLs that don't exist anymore with a question mark.

Answer (score 0):

(1) You'll have to get your sitemap redone and have GoogleBot reindex your site. [Google Webmaster Tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/) should be the place to do that.

(2) You could redirect the invalid links to a 404 page using your .htaccess file

Comment: I've  submitted my updated site map with google webmaster tools. so thats done.  How would i make a blanket redirect in my htaccess file? and would that mess up my other links somehow?

Comment: You'd have to write up a rewrite rule to map the ?blah to blah or to a 404 page. It's tricky because ?blah isn't a query, so you can't use query string to process out the ?. I tried paying around with some rules right now, but no luck.